# using jquery add values in a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Am new to jquery.
i have one jsp form in that i call javascript function in onload.
i want to load some values in a combobox which is in iframe using jquery-1.4.2.js but am not able to add.

please any one give solutions
thanks in advance

## hear is my jsp code

```
      <body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="javascript:getStateCountryDetail(<%=companyId%>,1,<%=countryId%>, <%=stateId%>)">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
           <td width="100%" align="left" style="padding:3px" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" width="100%" bordercolor="#cce7fa" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
                                    <iframe id = "applyMultipleInnerFrame" src ="/jsp/careers/applyMultipleCandidateResumeData.jsp?companyid=<%=companyId%>" name="applyMultipleInnerFrame" width="1100px" height="197px" frameborder="0" scrolling="Yes"></iframe>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

## Hear is my iframe jsp

i contains dropdown list

```
<body>
<form name="applyMultipleCandidateResumeData"  method="POST" target="_top" action="http://<%=sName%>/jsp/careers/jobListingMainPage.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="left"  width="100%" border=1 bordercolor="#ff9900" cellspacing=0 cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
                <td nowrap width="10%" align="left" style="border-color:#ff9900;color: black; font: 11px verdana;padding:2px" >
                    <input type="text" maxlength="64" size="9" value="" name="candidateCity_<%= i %>" id="candidateCity_<%= i %>" />
                </td>
                <td nowrap width="10%" align="left" style="border-color:#ff9900;color: black; font: 11px verdana;padding:2px" >
                        <select id = "candidateCountry_<%= i %>" name="candidateCountry_<%= i %>" class="controlStyle" onChange="loadState(this.value,'<%=i%>');">
                           <option value="0">-------- Select --------</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td nowrap width="10%" align="left" style="border-color:#ff9900;color: black; font: 11px verdana;padding:2px" >
                <select id="candidateState_<%= i %>" name="candidateState_<%= i %>" class="controlStyle">
                    <option value="0">----------- Select ---------</option>
                </select>
                </td>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

i use the following code to get the iframe object using jquery but i dont know whether it correct or not

```
var frm = $("#applyMultipleInnerFrame").contents());
```

## Here is my jquery code

`xmlDoc` is my jsone response which contains country list

```
var frm = $("#applyMultipleInnerFrame").contents());  
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
     if ($(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + ']') && $(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + '] option')) {
        $(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + '] option').length = 0;
        if (xmlDoc.countryList) {
            $(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + '] option')[$(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + '] option').length] = new Option("-- Select --", 0);
            for (var k = 0; k < xmlDoc.countryList.length; k++) {
                $(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + '] option')[$(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + '] option').length] = new Option(xmlDoc.countryList[k].name, xmlDoc.countryList[k].id);

                if ((xmlDoc.countryList[k].id) == dCountryId) {
                    alert($($(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + ']').text()));
                    //alert($(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_'+i+']').val(dCountryId).text());
                    //$(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_"+i+"] option').eq(dCountryId).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
                }
            }
        }
        //alert($(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_'+i+']) option:selected').text());
        //processAjaxRequestPost('ajaxRequestPost','SingleListHandler','getStateListDetails', eval('frm.candidateCountry_'+i).options[eval('frm.candidateCountry_'+i).selectedIndex].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really cache `$(frm)` instead of calling it over and over: `var $frm = $(frm);` and then use `$frm`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't (easily) modify the contents of iframes, since they have their own DOM. If the content in the iframe is coming from you, (say, page1.html contains an iframe containing page2.html), and not an external source, you can plug your script into page2.html so you don't have to do cross-DOM tricks (I've been there - it sucks).

P.S. Your code looks like it swallowed a nuclear weapon. If you cleaned up the code and posted just the relevant parts I'm sure you'll get more help that way ;)

Answer (score 0):

To access the contents of an iframe, you have to use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

> The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of
>   an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

---

Now about your code, it really messy.
Here are some points to keep in mind when writing jquery code:

- querying is not efficient, cache as often as possible your queries (for fixed elements for instance)

  ```
  var $frm = $(frm); // then use $frm
  ```
- to create markup, the most efficient way is to build the html as text and append the whole block at once.
- `jQuery('') (or $(''))` always returns an object. To check your query returned a result, check the `length` property

Here is a piece of optimized code:

```
// cache the elements you're going to use    
var $frm = $(frm),
    $candidCountry = $(frm).find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + ']');

// always check the length property to verify your query returned results
// because $('') always returns
if ($candidCountry.length && $candidCountry.find('option').length) {

    var html;

    if (xmlDoc.countryList) {

        // build the html as text
        html += '<option value="0">-- Select --</option>';

        for (var k = 0; k < xmlDoc.countryList.length; k++) {
            html += '<option value="'+xmlDoc.countryList[k].id+'">'+xmlDoc.countryList[k].name+'</option>';
        }
    }

    // append the whole html at once
    $candidCountry.html(html);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....i changed my code style to your code style but am not get result. please tell me how can i get the iframe object using jquery

Comment: I think you should use `var $candidCountry = $("#applyMultipleInnerFrame").contents().find('input[name=candidateCountry_' + i + ']')`

Comment: frame id = applyMultipleInnerFrame and iframe jsp form id = applyMultipleCandidateResumeData i try to get the form object                                                           var frm = $('#applyMultipleInnerFrame').contents().find('#applyMultipleCandidateResumeData');

Comment: WHy don't you do an ajax request to get the data instead of using an iframe ? Working with iframes is tricky...